# MongoDB tree with parent references

Tags: java, mongodb, tree, driver, nosql

I'm trying to create a tree to store information ordered by a path, for example:
.../data/cars/toyota
.../data/cars/fiat

The issue I'm finding is the Java syntax itself, how do I create the parents and the childs?
I've read the following links thoroughly but I am still unable to develop what I need in java:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521713/Storing-Tree-like-Hierarchy-Structures-With-MongoD

Can you please provide me with a simple Java code snippet that allows to create a tree + create parent and create a child for that parent?

Thank you very much in advance.

I am now trying this to create the root:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(DataColl);
BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject("_id", appId);
data.put("path", null);
coll.insert(data);
```

and this to create the childs:

```
    public boolean insertIntoDocument(String appId, String url, String data) {
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(DataColl);
    String[] array = url.split("/");
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("_id", array[array.length-1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(i == array.length-1)
            obj.put("path", array[i]);
        else
            obj.put("path", array[i]+",");
    }
    coll.insert(obj);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer on my own, hopefully this will help some newbie in the future. This code receives a url such as a/b/c and creates a tree. I use the appId as root, you could use something like user Identifier (each user gets its url), ect.

```
public boolean insertIntoDocument(String appId, String url, String data) {
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(DataColl);
    String[] array = url.split("/");
    String tempURL = appId;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("_id", array[i]);
        if (i == array.length - 1) {
            tempURL += ","+array[i];
            obj.put("path", tempURL);
            obj.append("data", data);
        } else {
            tempURL += ","+array[i];
            obj.put("path", tempURL);
        }
        if(!elementExistsInDocument(appId, tempURL))
            coll.insert(obj);
    }
    return true;
```